# amCharts Long legend names not right-aligning

Tags: amcharts

I'm having some trouble displaying my legend correctly.

I've tried putting it into it's own container, but I cannot get the items to right align neatly.

Any suggestions? (omitted some sensitive data)

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of the legend container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this with

`chart.legend.maxWidth = undefined;`